# How to customize Pagination in Primefaces Data Table

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Primefaces Datatable have lot of options to arrange pagination. 
I have a requirement to make Paginator as in following image :

[image]

Does any one have any idea how to do that. Please Suggest any alternate ways, if you know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extend PrimeFaces `DataTableRenderer` and override `encodePaginatorMarkup()`:

```
import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer;

public class MyDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodePaginatorMarkup(FacesContext context, DataTable table, String position, String tag, String styleClass) throws IOException {
        // Copypaste here the original PF source code and make modifications where necessary.
    }

}
```

*(you can find source code for the method in [the `DataRenderer` class](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/renderkit/DataRenderer.java) it is extending from)*

Then, to get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <description>Overrides the PrimeFaces table renderer with customized paginator.</description>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: It works for PageLinks up to the moment that I click one of the buttons

Comment: any chance to extend this answer so custom code will not dissapear after changing page? or how to attach onclick event to different tag than <span> on page number links.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of extending the PrimeFaces `DataTableRenderer` and overriding `encodePaginatorMarkup()` as suggested above, you can **add your own implementation** of the `org.primefaces.component.paginator.PaginatorElementRenderer` to the standard set of supported paginator elements.

This can be achieved by calling the following static method in your JSF ApplicationFactory implementation:

```
org.primefaces.renderkit.DataRenderer.addPaginatorElement("{myPaginator}", new MyPaginatorImplementation());
```

Subsequently you need to add the `MyPaginatorImplementation` class, which must implement the interface `org.primefaces.component.paginator.PaginatorElementRenderer`.

As a starting point, you can begin your customization from the PrimeFaces `PageLinksRenderer` class, e.g.

```
public class MyPaginatorImplementation implements PaginatorElementRenderer {

    public void render(FacesContext context, UIData uidata) throws IOException {
        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        int currentPage = uidata.getPage();
        int pageLinks = uidata.getPageLinks();
        int pageCount = uidata.getPageCount();
        int visiblePages = Math.min(pageLinks, pageCount);

        //calculate range, keep current in middle if necessary
        int start = Math.max(0, (int) Math.ceil(currentPage - ((visiblePages) / 2)));
        int end = Math.min(pageCount - 1, start + visiblePages - 1);

        //check when approaching to last page
        int delta = pageLinks - (end - start + 1);
        start = Math.max(0, start - delta);

        writer.startElement("span", null);
        writer.writeAttribute("class", UIData.PAGINATOR_PAGES_CLASS, null);

        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            String styleClass = currentPage == i ? UIData.PAGINATOR_ACTIVE_PAGE_CLASS : UIData.PAGINATOR_PAGE_CLASS;

            writer.startElement("span", null);
            writer.writeAttribute("class", styleClass, null);
            writer.writeAttribute("tabindex", 0, null);
            writer.writeText((i + 1), null);
            writer.endElement("span");
        }

        writer.endElement("span");
    } 
}
```

Now you can use this in your XHTML in the standard way provided by PrimeFaces, e.g.

`<p:dataTable paginatorTemplate="{myPaginator}" />`

The advantages of this alternative to the other options are:

- You can use the information in the UIData element (such as the first and last displayed row). This is not available in custom facets in the datalist / datatable.
- You can reuse this in every datatable and/or datalist in your application, preventing duplicate coding of your templates in the xhtml.

But at the cost of the extra java code required.

Comment: Noted should be that this is new since PrimeFaces 5.2 and wasn't possible in older versions.

Comment: static method in your JSF ApplicationFactory implementation: means what?

Comment: @Rajesh It's simple: you need a hook to call method `addPaginatorElement` exactly once. A simple example by extending the OmniFaces application factory could be:  
    `public class MyApplicationFactory extends OmniApplicationFactory {`  
        `/* constructor omitted */`  
        `@Override public Application getApplication() {`  
            `org.primefaces.renderkit.DataRenderer.addPaginatorElement("{myPaginator}", new MyPaginatorImplementation());`    
                `return super.getApplication(); } }`

Comment: Is there any chance to access the number of selected rows and display something like "Entries: 1 - 20 of 427 (3 selected)" in the paginator?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a easy way to achieve what you want. Currently the Paginator Template of `p:dataTable` supports the following options:

1. CurrentPageReport
2. FirstPageLink
3. PreviousPageLink
4. NextPageLink
5. LastPageLink
6. PageLinks
7. RowsPerPageDropdown
8. JumpToPageDropdown

Look into the source code of the class `org.primefaces.renderkit.DataRenderer` you can have these options available. What you want you need to do by developing custom datatable or by modifying the source. Primefaces currently don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `{RowsPerPageDropdown} of {totalPage}`