# Reading correct number of rows to display for a primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a primafaces datatable like this

```
 <pf:dataTable id="#{controller.tableComponentId}" 
     rows="#{controller.rowsPerPage}"
     rowsPerPageTemplate="#{controller.rowsPerPageTemplate}"

    <pf:ajax event="page" listener="#{controller.onPageChange}"/>
  />
```

My problem is that when the user changed the number of rows to be displayed. The page event is fired but with the old value of rows. So if the initial value of rows was 10, then the user changed it into 25. I still read the value 10 then JSF calls the rowsPerPage setter.

I am aware of this thread [PrimeFaces dataTable: how to catch rows-per-page event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381846/primefaces-datatable-how-to-catch-rows-per-page-event) It is basically the same problem. I tried the solution mentioned here but it didnt work for me. I also use pagination but for the simplicity i didn't put it in my code.

I also tried to use process="@form" and read the request parameter map, but the "dt_rppDD" value is not sent in the ajax request. Any other suggestions how to do that ?

Comment: rowsPerPage setter is triggered on RENDER_RESPONSE, after `onPageChange(PageEvent event)` fired. If you need new rows value, you can get it as `Faces.getRequestParameter(((UIComponent)event.getSource()).getClientId().concat("_rows"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Getting rows in page event listener

Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Datatable Page</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable id="#{datatablePage.tableComponentId}" rows="#{datatablePage.rows}" paginator="true"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="#{datatablePage.rowsPerPageTemplate}" value="#{datatablePage.list}" var="row">
            <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{datatablePage.onPageChange}"/>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{row}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Backing bean:

```
package org.antonu17;

import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
import org.omnifaces.util.Faces;
import org.primefaces.event.data.PageEvent;

import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

@Named("datatablePage")
@ViewScoped
public class DatatablePage implements Serializable {
    private String tableComponentId = "table";
    private Integer rows = 20;
    private String rowsPerPageTemplate = "20,30,40,50";

    private List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1,200).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

    public void onPageChange(PageEvent event) {
        System.out.println(Faces.getRequestParameter(((UIComponent)event.getSource()).getClientId().concat("_rows")));
    }

    public String getTableComponentId() {
        return tableComponentId;
    }

    public void setTableComponentId(String tableComponentId) {
        this.tableComponentId = tableComponentId;
    }

    public Integer getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(Integer rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public String getRowsPerPageTemplate() {
        return rowsPerPageTemplate;
    }

    public void setRowsPerPageTemplate(String rowsPerPageTemplate) {
        this.rowsPerPageTemplate = rowsPerPageTemplate;
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it is a solution to the original problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem but it was irrelevant to the question I asked. As i used my own implementation for `PaginatorElementRenderer` , JSF didn't use my class but the default one.

The question in this link is explaining my problem and solution.

[How to customize Pagination in Primefaces Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336432/how-to-customize-pagination-in-primefaces-data-table)

As i am using older version than 5.1 I had to use reflection to access the map and set my own class.